# Python - Unable to find assembly 'OSIsoft.AFSDK'

Tags: python, oracle, osisoft

I am trying to import "clr" in a python script and I have an error with and without "clr" installed. If "clr" is installed, then I get the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReference'
```

If I remove "clr" and install pythonnet (as suggested to fix the "clr" error), then I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundException: Unable to find assembly 'OSIsoft.AFSDK'.
   at Python.Runtime.CLRModule.AddReference(String name)
```

My imports look like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PIPC\\AF\\PublicAssemblies\\4.0\\')
import clr
clr.AddReference('OSIsoft.AFSDK')
from OSIsoft.AF.PI import *
from OSIsoft.AF.Search import *
from OSIsoft.AF.Asset import *
from OSIsoft.AF.Data import *
from OSIsoft.AF.Time import *
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
```

It seems like I'm missing something in finding the answer. I have loaded the latest oracle client 14.1 and that folder resided in my python working script environment. thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove be the wrong 'clr' module. which is mixed up with the one in pythonnet.

```
pip uninstall clr
pip uninstall pythonnet
```

```
pip install pythonnet
```